# NoMethodError with Rails app deployed to Heroku (When calling .create on model)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am writing a Ruby on Rails web application to be deployed on Heroku.

The development database is SQLite and the production database is PostgreSQL.

Everything works locally in the development and test environments, and worked on Heroku up until the last batch of revisions. Suddenly, attempting to create an instance of the Customer model is throwing

```
'NoMethodError undefined method `each' for nil:nilclass'.
```

The migrations have definitely been run, I have tried pg:reset and re-running migrations, and I have also tried restarting heroku.

If I open the rails console on heroku and try to call any of the following methods I get the same error

`Customer.count`
`Customer.create(...)`
`Customer.new`

Can anyone help resolve this issue?

EDIT:

Stacktrace when running rails db:migrate with Postgres DB ( no errors with SQLite )

```
** Invoke db:_dump (first_time)
** Execute db:_dump
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config
** Execute db:schema:dump
rails aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/descriptive_statistics-2.5.1/lib/descriptive_statistics/support/convert.rb:37:in `to_array'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/descriptive_statistics-2.5.1/lib/descriptive_statistics/support/convert.rb:8:in `convert'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/descriptive_statistics-2.5.1/lib/descriptive_statistics/sum.rb:3:in `sum'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/enumerable.rb:185:in `sum'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:659:in `sequence_name_from_parts'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:631:in `new_column_from_field'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:115:in `block in columns'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:114:in `map'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:114:in `columns'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/schema_dumper.rb:112:in `table'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/schema_dumper.rb:100:in `block in tables'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/schema_dumper.rb:99:in `each'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/schema_dumper.rb:99:in `tables'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/schema_dumper.rb:44:in `dump'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/schema_dumper.rb:28:in `dump'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:377:in `block in dump_schema'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:376:in `open'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:376:in `dump_schema'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:392:in `block (4 levels) in <main>'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:390:in `each'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:390:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `synchronize'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:97:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `synchronize'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:88:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `synchronize'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
/Users/harilimaye/Documents/CompSci/Year 2/SEG/smg/alpaca_online_banking/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
/Users/harilimaye/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
/Users/harilimaye/Documents/CompSci/Year 2/SEG/smg/alpaca_online_banking/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: show the stacktrace

Comment: Thank you - I have edited question to include stack trace

Comment: Look at `app/models/customer.rb:45`, method `createCustomers`

Comment: Yes, so this factory method just generates 1 or more customer hashes and calls Customer.create! with them. I have tried calling Customer.create! on the heroku rails console and I get this error, which seems very odd. I am not explicitly calling 'each' anywhere, it seems to be produced by calling any of the Customer model class methods that involve database interaction

Comment: If so, then something calls that factory method (a `before_*` hook? a validation?) And the factory method has a bug in it (attempt to iterate a collection that is `nil`).

Comment: To clarify in the factory method line 45 is just calling Customer.create! (with an array of hashes), when I run Customer.create on irb rails console on heroku it gives the same error so I din't think its a problem with the factory method

Comment: That array of hashes is nil then, apparently. The stacktrace clearly points to that line.

Comment: Hm I see where you’re coming from but the empty array is created above in the method so couldn’t be nil, and it also doesn’t explain that the same error occurs on the console when calling .create or .new or .count

Comment: Well yes, to explain that, I'd need to see a [mcve]. Guessing over the internet can only get you so far.

Comment: Can you share the `createCustomers` method code that the error is referencing?

Comment: ```def createCustomers(howMany)
      # Check valid quantity
      if howMany.between? 1, 50
        # array to store hashes to create new customers
        new_customers = []
        # generate 'howMany' new customer hashes
        howMany.times do
          new_customers.push(getCustomerHash)
        end
        # create the customers in the database
        Customer.create!(new_customers)
        # return success
        true
      else
        false
      end
    end```

Comment: and getCustomerHash returns a randomly generated valid customer hash

Comment: That may be minimal, alright, but not complete or reproducible.

Comment: Please [edit] the question with additional info, not in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance all, I seem to have sorted it. I've edited the question with the solution.

Comment: @HariLimaye: congrats on finding the answer. Instead of adding the solution to the question, the proper way would be to add a self-answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turned out the problem was due to the inclusion of **gem 'transaction_faker'** in my gem-file, which added the module descriptive_statistics (the source of the problem). My GUESS is that it must override the sum method of the Enumerable module used in the conversion from migration to Postgres, or something along those lines.